# What type of school is Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Based on the [government approved types](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-school/overview) of school, what type of schools is Hogwarts?

I believe it would be somewhat like a Foundation School where it is state funded and has a governing body that technically owns the grounds.

Comment: its a school of whichcraft and wizardry

Comment: Whichcraft?  Oh, thatcraft.

Comment: Do they also teach [Dance Magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4gABvUhhkg)?

Answer (score 6):

**None of the above.** The school is evidently funded by a separate [non-governmental body](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ministry_of_Magic) that exists within the UK but isn't answerable to the UK government. On that basis (and taking into account that the school is neither licensed, nor inspected by any Local Education Authority nor OFSTED) I would have to say that the closest description of it is that it's not a school in any discernible sense of the word but rather a private club for children of school age.

Because education is definitely taking place and because none of the teachers hold QTS status, you could *possibly* argue that it's a private academy of some sort (if you squint and turn your head sideways). It would certainly be illegal to operate on that basis so at the very best it's an **illegal private academy.**

Comment: I would throw my hat in with Acadamy. Also I'd argue that it's run and funded by the Wizard Government/MoM.

Comment: @Pureferret - Don't even get me started on their policies on physical punishment of students, failure of duty of care, lapses in school safety, Health and Safety violations. I counted at least 30-40 crimes committed in Chapters 6 + 7 that would get any normal school closed instantly.

Comment: @Richard - you are forgetting that Wizarding society runs by the model of between 400 and 100 years ago. Gotta make an adjustment for that

Comment: plus, they have a ginormously sized vicious basilisk underneath :D its enough to get the licenses cancelled :D

Comment: I'm willing to entertain discussion that it's an Embassy school.

Comment: Does mix of acadamy+free school sound about right?

Comment: @GregoryOakley-stevenson - Given that their entry is wholly selective (and indeed based on ethnicity) there's no way they'd get free school status.